# set items dynamically to vis timeline in react context

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a react component to load a vis timeline. The code below is working

```
require("../../../node_modules/vis/dist/vis.css");
require("../../../node_modules/vis/dist/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css");
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const vis = require('vis');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');



var items = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2013-04-20'},
    {id: 2, content: 'item 2', start: '2013-04-14'},
    {id: 3, content: 'item 3', start: '2013-04-18'},
    {id: 4, content: 'item 4', start: '2013-04-16', end: '2013-04-19'},
    {id: 5, content: 'item 5', start: '2013-04-25'},
    {id: 6, content: 'item 6', start: '2013-04-27'}
  ]);
    var options = {};



var Timeline = createReactClass({
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("componentDidMount",this.refs);
            var timeline = new vis.Timeline(this.refs.myRef, items, options);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div ref="myRef"></div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Timeline />,
  document.getElementById('timeline')
);
```

Now I want to set my items in order to update my timeline. How can I replace

```
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(this.refs.myRef, items, options);
```

By something like

```
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(this.refs.myRef, <Items />, options);
```